# Assign cookie's value to the input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m trying  to assign cookie's value to the input field.
code

Javascript

```
if ($.cookie("clientcookie")) {                 
var cookieval = $.cookie("clientcookie");            
var inputs = document.getElementById("search");                                 
inputs.value =cookieval;
}
```

HTML

```
<input id="search" type="search" placeholder="Search Text" class="input-medium search-query" >
```

But its not working its says:

```
Use of attributes' specified attribute is deprecated. It always returns true.
inputs.value =cookieval;
```

and

```
TypeError: inputs is null
```

I also tried

```
$('#search').val(cookieval);
```

But not working.
How to assign value to the input field

Comment: pls append the HTML of the input to the question. Do you have the javascript wrapped in a `$(document).ready();` closure?

Comment: @DanFromGermany : Yes its inside the $(document).ready()

Comment: @DaveBriand :jquery.cookie.js

Comment: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie for others

Comment: I can't get this to not work. I'm using jQuery 1.10.2 and jquery.cookie.js v1.4.1 - can you put this in a fiddle?


Also - the way your setting the value is deprecated (per the error) - you should be using the $('#search').val() method you mentioned.


What do you get when you console out $.cookie("clientcookie")?

Comment: Can you clarify which browser you are using? Also, is there a particular reason you are using a "search" type input? Those are fairly rarely used type, and perhaps it misbehaves in some browsers.

Comment: Im using  mozila and crome

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    $.cookie("clientcookie",'test'); //setting cookie in browser

if ($.cookie("clientcookie")) {                 
    var cookieval = $.cookie("clientcookie");            
    var inputs = document.getElementById("search");                                 
    inputs.value =cookieval;
}
}catch(e){
    alert(e);
}
```

very simple:
1. check cookie exist
2. if so then extract its value
3. fill text field's value.

check working example in jsfilddle.

Comment: this is not an answer.u just put it in try catch block i.e i already did it.here in alert(e)its not executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think `if ($.cookie("clientcookie"))` is not proper way to check the cookie.

Try this.

```
if ($.cookie("clientcookie") !== null) {                 
    var cookieval = $.cookie("clientcookie");            
    var inputs = document.getElementById("search");                                 
    inputs.value =cookieval;
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QV5Dq/)

Comment: thanks for reply.But there is no issue with if ($.cookie("clientcookie"))>I check that by putting alerts in that.

Comment: have you put an alert inside of `if` block?

Comment: I tried this ..its says ...TypeError: inputs is null

Comment: Yes I put the alert inside the if